# Can NS3 be paired with real distributed algorithms?

Tags: network-programming, distributed-computing, distributed-system, ns-3, multi-agent

I have a distributed algorithm written by myself and I want to test how will it perform under different network situations. I find the network simulator 3, which is primarily used for network research. I'm curious, can I set it up to run some real algorithms for the Node/NetDevice and transmit real data between them?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible indeed. I did something similar for my master's degree (although in my case the distributed program was written in Java, you can have a look at it [here](https://amslaurea.unibo.it/20440/) if you're interested; JNA was needed to do so).

Basically, you should write your own [Application](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_application.html), which should contain the actual program you want to execute on the nodes. Different nodes can also run different applications.

There are some predefined Applications shipped with ns-3, such as [On-Off Application](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_on_off_application.html); you can take a look at them to understand how to build a new one. You can also take a look at [a simple library I wrote](https://github.com/gscaparrotti/ns3asy), which contains a simple Application that can send arbitrary data with arbitrary parameters (send rate, data rate, maximum bandwidth, etc...).